# Cannot target dynamically generated element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

[One of the pages I'm working on](http://jasonalanfitness.com/schedule-consultation/) has a modal containing a form which, when viewed on most mobile iOS devices, displays the caret/cursor in the wrong place when each input is focused. A number of people have reported this problem, including [this page here](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8).

On their advice, I was attempting to write some JS to hide the body content, etc. I'm having a hard time binding to the click event of the `.new-appt` and `.timeslot` elements.

I have tried:

A) `jQuery('.new-appt').click(function(){ alert(); });`

B) `jQuery('.timeslot').click(function(){ alert(); });`

C) `jQuery(document).on('click', '.new-appt', function(){ alert(); });`

D) `jQuery(document).on('click', '.timeslot', function(){ alert(); });`

E) `jQuery(document).live('click', '.new-appt', function(){ alert(); });`

F) `jQuery(document).live('click', '.timeslot', function(){ alert(); });`

And when pasted in the console, A through D seem to trigger fine, but not in a script block. I've also tried to placed them in a `jQuery(document).ready`, but that didn't seem to help.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach event listener to elements after these DOM elements are ready. In this case its moment when DOM in modal is ready. So basicaly you should register  click event at bottom of handler that open and creates content of this modal.